# How can I change GMSMapView padding without moving the map

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I'd like to be able change the padding of a GMSMapView *without* changing the location of a map.  Right now, Google Maps iOS SDK changes the map location so that the same point is in center after the padding has been applied.  This is different than how the Android SDK works, which just leaves the map as it is.

I've found a slight workaround for this, but it doesn't work consistently.  I can calculate what the new center location should be and update the map camera when I change the padding with the following...

```
UIEdgeInsets oldPadding = self.mapCtrl.map.padding;
UIEdgeInsets newPadding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);

float deltaX = ((newPadding.right - newPadding.left)/2 - (oldPadding.right-oldPadding.left)/2);
float deltaY = ((newPadding.top - newPadding.bottom)/2 - (oldPadding.top-oldPadding.bottom)/2);

GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate scrollByX:deltaX Y:deltaY];

[self.mapCtrl.map setPadding:newPadding];
[self.mapCtrl.map moveCamera:updatedCamera];
```

But I'd say it only works 50%.  The other 50% the map moves to the new padding location and then back to where I want it to be.

I see two possible solutions for this... A) change the padding in a different way so that it doesn't move the map, or B) figure out a way to get the above code to work by somehow pausing or grouping map movements so that both calls only go through at once.  But I can't figure out how to make either of those two things happen.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have the same padding on top and bottom so everything keeps centered.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs it in the future:

```swift
mapView.padding = newPadding
mapView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

That messes with the internals of `GMSMapView` though and the padding isn't applied to the map itself correctly, just to the UI.

I use the following code to re-apply the padding again after my animation so that the map behaves correctly again.

```swift
let newCenter = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: mapView.bounds.inset(by: newMapViewPadding).center)
mapView.padding = newMapViewPadding + UIEdgeInsets(all: 1)
mapView.padding = newMapViewPadding
mapView.moveCamera(GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(newCenter))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's correct that we need to set a padding with top AND bottom to keep things appearing correctly, but it's also important to do it AFTER attaching the view to it's parent.

I was doing it before and it did not work properly.